# cdkVirtualFor not loading all items

Tags: angular

I'm running into a small problem and I can't find the cause.
So I want to display a list from an observable (it returns 3 objects)
My problem is that only the first two items are displayed.
When I use a regular list all of them are appearing.

What did I do wrong ?

```
<div *ngIf="(clients$ | async) as clients; else loading">
    <cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport *ngIf="clients.length > 0; else noResult" itemSize="100" style="height:100vh">
        <mat-nav-list role="navigation" class="clients" fxLayout="row wrap" fxLayout.lt-sm="column" fxLayoutAlign="flex-start" fxLayoutGap="6px">
            <mat-list-item *cdkVirtualFor="let client of clients; templateCacheSize: 0" role="listitem" style="padding-bottom: 8px;">
                <h1>{{client.id}}</h1>
            </mat-list-item>
        </mat-nav-list>
    </cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>
    <ng-template #noResult>
        <div fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="space-evenly center">
            <h3>No result</h3>
        </div>
    </ng-template>
</div>
<ng-template #loading>
    <div fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="space-evenly center">
        <h3>Loading...</h3>
        <mat-progress-bar mode="indeterminate"></mat-progress-bar>
    </div>
</ng-template>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to be very sure that your [itemSize] precisely matches the *total height* (including padding/margin) of each item, or you'll encounter all sorts of strange bugs, likely including this bug.